# Autenticação via OAuth vs Sistema de login convencional. Qual usar?

Tags: banco-de-dados, oauth, oauth2

Imagine o seguinte cenário:

> Você está montando um projeto onde qualquer pessoa pode se cadastrar com dados básicos (nome, foto, idade) para utilizar seu produto. E como ele está na internet não há como prever o número de potenciais usuários que podem *brotar* de uma hora para outra.

Pois bem, pensando nesse aspecto, eu gostaria de saber se vale mais a pena utilizar as APIs fornecidas por empresas como Facebook, Twitter e Google para ter acesso aos dados destes usuários (oAuth), ou se *ainda* vale mais a pena manter o estilo de login tradicional, fornecendo um método de cadastro ao usuário e guardando suas informações em um servidor próprio.

Na minha opinião, aparentemente os pontos fortes de se utilizar oAuth seriam:

- Facilidade de cadastro por parte do usuário;
- Velocidade na obtenção dos dados;
- Economia de recursos (já que os dados vem via API externa);
- Dados sempre atualizados;

Mas como nunca mexi com este tipo de API eu sinceramente não sei dizer se vale a pena ou não, então, principalmente do ponto de vista de escalabilidade, vale mais a pena usar APIs oAuth ou login convencional (banco próprio)?

Comment: só uma observação, dê uma lida nessa notícia, porque é provável que autenticação via OAuth comece a ser pouco utilizada por algum tempo, talvez os usuários utilizem menos por causa dessa falha que você vai encontrar melhor na notícia.
http://www.techtudo.com.br/noticias/noticia/2014/05/falha-de-seguranca-afetam-logins-de-facebook-google-e-microsoft.html

Comment: @EnzoTiezzi acredito que ainda existem mais falhas que não foram descobertas, entretanto vale ressaltar a capacidade que o Facebook tem para resolver os problemas e mesmo assim ainda continua a ter mais credibilidade que um sistema próprio.

Comment: @Filipe Sim sim, foi só um toque pra dar uma olhada se isso iria afetar algo em seu desenvolvimento.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O que vou responder não é uma opinião, acredito que a maioria dos programadores irão concordar, o que a torna quase uma regra.

Existe vantagens e desvantagens de se utilizar o Facebook login e um sistema convencional.

**Facebook login - Principais vantagens**

1. Elimina a necessidade de se criar uma nova conta no seu site, basta apenas autorizar que seu aplicativo recolha as informações, evitando que o utilizador crie mais um login e senha;
2. Evita preencher longos formulários de inscrição;
3. Evita validação da conta por e-mail, uma vez que esse passo já foi realizado no momento da inscrição no Facebook;
4. Provavelmente as informações serão verdadeiras uma vez que são utilizadas no perfil do utilizador.
5. Actualização de dados no próprio Facebook, evitando que o utilizador fique com dados incorrectos na sua aplicação.

**Facebook login - Principais desvantagens**

1. Receio por parte de alguns utilizadores em disponibilizar dados em sites desconhecidos.
2. Actualizações da API do Facebook, o que pode originar falhas no login e consequentemente transtorno para os utilizadores. Resumindo é preciso acompanhar de perto a evolução da ferramenta.
3. Sujeito aos termos de utilização do Facebook, a final ninguém sabe quando o Zuckerberg vai acordar de mau humor e resolver cobrar pela utilização da ferramenta e acredite, com as recentes modificações no Facebook, não duvido!

Contudo utilize o login convencional, eu conheço pessoas que abandonaram ou simplesmente não utilizam o Facebook.

Se houver paciência, implemente também o login com o Google+ e o Twitter.

Pelo que entendi, a sua aplicação está no inicio, se as grandes empresas (como o Pinterest, Yahoo, etc... ) utilizam o login do Facebook para angariar novos utilizadores, quanto mais nós pobres mortais.

Comment: No final do dia vale mesmo a confiança do criador nas ferramentas existentes no mercado ou a necessidade de centralizar tudo. +1 pela informação.

Comment: @Filipe.Fonseca acredito que o objectivo do login com o Facebbok é centralizar tudo, mas isso só vai ser 100% eficaz no dia em que for obrigatório ter um perfil :) e mesmo assim um dia o Facebook cai e surge outro qualquer... e assim andamos de um lado para o outro!

Comment: 3 - Evita validação da conta por e-mail, uma vez que esse passo já foi realizado no momento da inscrição no Facebook;

Um adendo:
Email validado não é algo obrigatório pelo Facebook, explico:  eu tive um caso de alguém que se registrou no Facebook com um email 'falso' de um domínio meu e descobri pois recebia o 'pega-tudo' de emails. Reportei e o usuário manteve a conta com o esse email que 'não existe'.

Então essa confiança não pode ser plena de que já houve uma validação desse endereço